# which function is the replacement function of ‘pathFor’ function of iron-routing in flow-routing?

Tags: meteor, path, iron-router, flow-router

I use orionjs from meteor.js:
I change the blog example of the orionjs (https://github.com/orionjs/examples/tree/master/blog)

I use useraccounts:flow-routing replace useraccouts:iron-routing package:

```
<a href="{{ pathFor 'dictionary.update' }}">edit</a>
```

which package in charge of parsing and pathFor and what is that meaning?
If I continue use the flow-routing package how can I deal with the pathFor function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find arillo:flow-router-helpers package.
https://github.com/arillo/meteor-flow-router-helpers

which have a totally replace function "pathfor" there.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it using react and meteor and flow router

```
<a href="{FlowRouter.path('/')}">edit</a>
```

Have a look at this example for a use case https://github.com/arunoda/hello-react-meteor/blob/master/both/components/post_page.jsx#L14

And here for the documentation
https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowrouterpathpathdef-params-queryparams